# How to keep record of Urls opened on Chrome or Firefox in Android using Accessibility Service?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

**Problem:** 
User opens chrome or firefox application on Android , and keeps browsing for 'n' number of minutes. How can we keep track of the urls he opened?

**What I tried:**
Using Android's [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html) API I managed to get the Chrome Url when application opens at first by "Window Change Event". But after that while user is in chrome and browsing there is no event given by accessibility service (Obviously because there is no "window change event". Because everything is being done in the Chrome Application.

**Here is the code:**

```
public void dfs(AccessibilityNodeInfo info){
        if(info == null) {
            return;
        }
        if(info.getText() != null && info.getText().length() > 0)
            if(info.getText().toString().contains("http")) {

                System.out.println(info.getText() + " class: " + info.getClassName());
                }
            }
        for(int i=0;i<info.getChildCount();i++){
            AccessibilityNodeInfo child = info.getChild(i);
            dfs(child);
            if(child!=null) {
                child.recycle();
            }
    }
   }
```

Which event should I be looking into or How can I keep record of urls opened by user in chrome or firefox?